# How to retain outer div's border after adding an inner div

Tags: html, css

I created a div with a border-radius 4% and wanted to add a div inside it. But now the border-radius is getting affected. How can I add the new div without affecting the previous border-radius.

If I add same border radius for the inner div
[image]

Without any border-radius
[image]

```css
body {
    background: #4FA2AD;
}

.upper {
    background-color: #035961;
    height: 30%;
}

.main {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 25vh auto;
    border-radius: 4%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="upper">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I just add this on .upperr `border-top-left-radius: 4%;
    border-top-right-radius: 4%;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Overflow hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) will cut off any content that goes outside of the parents border, including any overlap at the corners.

`overflow: hidden;`

This is sometimes not a viable solution (Where you require content to overflow or extend the container) however since you have a fixed size, it is valid in this case.

```css
body {
    background: #4FA2AD;
}

.upper {
    background-color: #035961;
    height: 30%;
}

.main {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 25vh auto;
    border-radius: 4%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="upper">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```